# Generate variable name with string and value in Lua

Tags: string, variables, lua

Is there a function in Lua to generate a variable name with a string and a value?

For example, I have the first (string) part `"vari"` and the second (value) part, which can vary. So I want to generate `"vari1"`, `"vari2"`, `"vari3"` and so on. Something like this:
`"vari"..value = 42` should then be `vari1 = 42`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it most likely is a bad idea (and this very much seems to be an XY-problem to me). If you need an enumerated "list" of variables, just use a table:

```lua
local var = { 42, 100, 30 }
var[4] = 33 -- add a fourth variable
print(var[1]) -- prints 42
```

if you really need to set a bunch of variables though (perhaps to adhere to some odd API?), I'd recommend using [`("..."):format(...)`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.format) to ensure that your variables will be formatted as `var<int>` rather than `var1.0`, `var1e3` or the like.

Th environment in Lua - both the global environment `_G` and the environment of your script `_ENV` (in Lua 5.2), which usually is the global environment, are **just tables** in the end, so you can write to them and read from them the same way you'd write to and read from tables:

```lua
for value = 1, 3 do
    _ENV[("vari%d"):format(value)] = value^2
end
print(var3) -- prints 3*3 = 9
-- verbose ways of accessing var3:
print(_ENV.var3) -- still 9
print(_ENV["var"]) -- 9 as well
```

**Note that this is most likely just pollution of your script environment (likely global pollution) which is considered a bad practice (and often bad for performance). Please outline your actual problem and consider using the list approach.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Call:

```
rawset(table, key, value)
```

Example:

```
rawset(_G, 'foo', 'bar')
print(foo)
-- Output: bar
-- Lets loop it and rawget() it too
-- rawset() returns table _G here to rawget()
-- rawset() is executed before rawget() in this case
for i = 1, 10 do
 print(rawget(rawset(_G, 'var' .. i, i), 'var' .. i))
end
-- Output: 10 lines - First the number 1 and last the number 10
```

See: https://lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-rawset

Putting all together and create an own function...

```
function create_vars(var, start, stop)
for i = start, stop do
 print(var .. i, '=>', rawget(rawset(_G, var .. i, i), var .. i))
end
end
```

And use it...

```
> create_vars('var', 42, 42)
var42   =>  42
> print(var42)
42
```

Comment: This is needlessly complicated. What's wrong with `table[key] = value`?

Comment: Nothing. - But @Bladehunt0 asked for a function.

Comment: But your code will do the wrong thing if there's a metatable on _ENV.

Comment: I don't necessarily need a function. To simplify it: I have a number which can vary, lets say 42. Then I want to generate 42 variables named "cont1, cont2, cont3 .. cont40, cont41, cont42" the char part (cont) rests the same.

Comment: Or more simple, I just have to know how I can create a variable name out of "cont" and "12", so that I can use it like a normal variable name (cont12 = 69)

Comment: Exactly this you can do with ```rawset()``` and ```rawget()```. - The concatenation of the string "var" with the two dots ```..``` and the number ```42``` creates a key ```var42``` that value will be set to ```42```. The same in a normal function like ```print()``` produces the string: "var42"

Comment: The normal and more uncomplicated and mostly used constructor for that, and that is what @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica points to, could look like: ```_G["var" .. 1] = 42```